# how to pass data as props around components situated in diffrent files in react

Tags: reactjs, components

i'm new to react..
so cutting straight to the question,

1. seed.js < holds an array of object type data.
2. main.js < is a component reads the data from seed and returns data as props to sub
3. sub.js  < receives data from the main.js and renders it in a loop, so that it can render every data from seed.

How to import and use it right (in simplest form)? The props happens to be very confusing to me (how to pass it around between components in different files)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output. SO isn't a free coding service, you can't ask people to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Context from react

```
Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.
```

or otherwise you have to pass from parent to child

or you can use redux /redux-saga to store that record and use it any where but I prefer Context Api from react that is much use full in your scenario.

Refernce for your issue : https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html